# How to reproduce BadRequestError: request aborted

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I am working on Express based application.
I see the following error on the error logs on production. Apparently, they are happening only on Safari browser.
It's happening when an api request is sent to a certain endpoint from frontend.
I know it's `raw-body` module that throws this error. But I don't know how to make `raw-body`(related to `body-parser`) throws this error to reproduce this case.

```
BadRequestError: request aborted (Most recent call first)
at IncomingMessage.onAborted (/app/node_modules/raw-body/index.js line 231 col 9)
228  function onAborted () {
229    if (complete) return
230
231    done(createError(400, 'request aborted', {
231      code: 'ECONNABORTED',
232      expected: length,
233      length: length,
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js line 197 col 8)
at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (async_hooks.js line 197 col 8)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js line 412 col 34)
```

**The following is more detailed info about what's going on.**

When the user redirected to the web page, it sends POST request to the backend to report events for data analysis.

```
        var abortController = new AbortController();
        var fetchTimeoutId = setTimeout(
          abortController.abort.bind(abortController),
          NETWORK_TIMEOUT_MS
        );
        fetch('/checkout/event', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            eventName: eventName,
            otherInfo: otherInfo
          }),          
          signal: abortController.signal,
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
          },
        })
          .catch(console.error)
          .finally(function () {
            clearTimeout(fetchTimeoutId);
          });
```

Sometimes, the request is not handled by the router(controller) and it gets caught by error handler of express. Also, I don't think it's caused by AbortController on the frontend. I confirmed AbortController doesn't abort what's already being run on the backend.
I just want to know why and how this is happening on Safari browsers.

Comment: remote party (backend) closing connection - without providing details, please provide more details regarding Your backend and frontend code (not module code) to have idea what's happening

Comment: @num8er 
Thanks for the comment. I was hoping to reproduce it the way users could do such as closing the browsers.
I added some details above. If anything is missing, let me know

Comment: seems like timeout makes abort controller close the connection. Try to define 30000 (30 sec) to NETWORK_TIMEOUT_MS. If it will work, so, seems like backend responds to long, or there is an error which holds response - most NodeJS developers does not handle errors properly so backend keeps hanging until timeout.

Comment: addition to previous comment I suspect that NETWORK_TIMEOUT_MS is undefined, which causes immediate timeout. So try with hardcoded 30000

Comment: @num8er
NETWORK_TIMEOUT_MS is already set to 20000. I set it to 1 to test it but it doesn't close the connection. It keeps the backend running although fetch fails on the frontend.
It doesn't abort the request on the backend and returns 200.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was that I was destructuring headers from the request from my frontend directly into a request to another backend that was expecting json. This was setting my Content-Type header to something other than application/json, thus screwing up body-parser. So I removed `{ ...req.headers }` in my axios request and explicitly put `{ "Content-Type": "application/json" }` and it solved my error. Hope that helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

here is a 1mb [text](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/khaykov/a6105154becce4c0530da38e723c2330/raw/41ab415ac41c93a198f7da5b47d604956157c5c3/gistfile1.txt)

copy that text, send it to any of your post endpoints via postman, and cancel the request the second you fire it, if it didn't work use like 5mb (paste the gist text 5 times).
that's how I came to reproduce it.